# How to create an array list of a member variable of a dataclass

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist

I have a dataclass:

```
data class MoviesInSeries(
    val originalMovieName: String,

// If there's no value of parameter, assign it as null
    val movieInSeries1Name: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries1Date: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries1Rating: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries1Pic: Int? = null,

    val movieInSeries2Name: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries2Date: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries2Rating: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries2Pic: Int? = null,
    )
```

I've created two objects of it.

```
fun getRestOfSeriesMovies(): ArrayList<MoviesInSeries> {
    val movieList = ArrayList<MoviesInSeries>()

    val s_gi_joe = MoviesInSeries("G.I. Joe: Retaliation", "G.I. Joe: The Rise of Cobra",
        "2009","Pg-13",  R.drawable.gijtsofmp)
    movieList.add(s_gi_joe)

    val s_gi_joe2 = MoviesInSeries("G.I. Joe: Retaliation2", "G.I. Joe: The Rise of Cobra",
        "2009","Pg-13",  R.drawable.gijtsofmp)
    movieList.add(s_gi_joe)


    return movieList
}
```

Now I want to create an array list of the `originalMovieName` member. I'll later use that to check if a certain string is in it. How would I do that?

Comment: The date class differs from the usual one in that its methods are automatically created and overridden `toString`, `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `copy()`. Can you describe in more detail what you want to do?

Comment: I want to create an array list of the member `originalMovies`. I'll have a for example a val of "x". I'll use the array list that I created to to check if (array list).contains(x) to check if it contains the x value. got it?

Comment: _val allOriginalMovieNames = getRestOfSeriesMovies().map { it.originalMovieName }_

Comment: Yupe, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a lot of weird things happening in your model class :

1-

```
checkIFMovieNameExist(getRestOfSeriesMovies())
fun checkIFMovieNameExist(list: List<MoviesInSeries>,value:String): MoviesInSeries? {
    return list.find { it.originalMovieName == value }
}
```

2-from time of creation:

```
data class MoviesInSeries(
    val originalMovieName: String,

// If there's no value of parameter, assign it as null
    val movieInSeries1Name: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries1Date: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries1Rating: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries1Pic: Int? = null,

    val movieInSeries2Name: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries2Date: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries2Rating: String? = null,
    val movieInSeries2Pic: Int? = null,
){
    init {
        names.add(originalMovieName)
    }
companion object {
    private val names: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    fun getMoviesNames():List<String>{
        return names
    }
}
}
```

then you can check if a name exist in names list in any place in the code

```
MoviesInSeries("sd1")
MoviesInSeries("sd2")
MoviesInSeries("sd3")
MoviesInSeries("sd4")
println(MoviesInSeries. getMoviesNames().contains("sd1"))
```